# Conservation of dimension of linear maps and its consequences

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

I refer to this note, page 9:
http://www.math.harvard.edu/~ctm/home/text/class/harvard/55a/09/html/home/course/course.pdf

> **Theorem 5.1 (Conservation of dimension)** 
>    For any linear map $T : V \to
> W$, we have $\dim V = \dim \ker T + \dim \text{Im}\, T$.
>
> **Corollary 5.2** There exists a basis for $V$ and $W$ such that $T$ has the form
>   of a projection followed by an inclusion: $T : \mathbb{R}^n → \mathbb{R}^i \subset \mathbb{R}^j.$

How is 5.2 a corollary of 5.1? I guess he's talking about projection of $T$ onto the complementary subspace of $\ker T$, but I still need some clarification, as $T$ is a map on $V$ and then suddenly $\mathbb{R}^n$ out of nowhere, is he taking about $A : \mathbb{R}^n → \mathbb{R}^i \subset \mathbb{R}^j$ with $A = [T]_{B_V}^{B_W}$ ?
 Isn't this the first Isomorphism theorem? I can prove all this, but I still need clarifications on the connection here.

> This result shows that not only is the theory of finite-dimensional vector
>   spaces trivial (they are classified by their dimension), but **the theory of maps
>   between different vector spaces V and W is also trivial.**

I need more exposition on this, too. What does he mean? trivial in what sense? say, every $n$ dimension vector space $V$ over $F$ can be reduced to $F^n$ by isomorphism so we only need to study $F^n$, so it is said that such vector spaces are trivial. Then what's the analogous situation for linear maps between different vector spaces?